# Listar impresoras del lado del cliente (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Tengo una aplicación corriendo en servidor y quiero poder detectar las impresoras que estén accesibles desde un ordenador xs.

Es decir, del lado del cliente quiero que se listen las impresoras y actualmente, como la aplicación la estoy corriendo desde un servidor, me muestra las impresoras que están accesibles desde el servidor.

La idea es que desde donde se vaya a acceder a la aplicación, o sea desde un ordenador xs, se puedan listar sus respectivas impresoras.

No se si un camino puede ser obteniendo la dirección ip de ese ordenador pero la verdad no he podido encontrar la manera de resolverlo con lo que tengo que viene siendo esto:

```
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
List <String> Impresoras= new ArrayList<>();
// -- ver los atributos de las impresoras...

for (PrintService printService : services) {

Impresoras.add(printService.getName());
System.out.println(" ---- IMPRESORA: " + printService.getName());

PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = printService.getAttributes();

System.out.println("--- atributos");

// todos los atributos de la impresora
Attribute[] a = printServiceAttributeSet.toArray();
for (Attribute unAtribute : a) {
System.out.println("atributo: " + unAtribute.getName());
}

System.out.println("--- viendo valores especificos de los atributos ");

// valor especifico de un determinado atributo de la impresora
System.out.println("PrinterLocation: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterLocation.class));
System.out.println("PrinterInfo: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterInfo.class));
System.out.println("PrinterState: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterState.class));
System.out.println("Destination: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(Destination.class));
System.out.println("PrinterMakeAndModel: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterMakeAndModel.class));
System.out.println("PrinterIsAcceptingJobs: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterIsAcceptingJobs.class));
```

Aquí obtengo el servicio que me listas las impresoras pero esto lo hace en donde se corra la aplicación.

Si me podrían dar una pista se los agradecería mucho pues no se mucho de Java y estoy probando con ejemplos.

Saludos!

Comment: Y en la parte cliente.. ¿qué hay?

Comment: @SJuan76 Pues tengo una modal que muestra la lista de las impresoras al pasar la lista por medio de un controlador a la vista. Algo simple para poder luego escoger la impresora que deseo y mandar el documento a imprimir por ella. Pero como dije anteriormente, eso pasa solo cuando la aplicación corre local en la computadora. Si abro la que tengo en el servidor, muestra las impresoras que él ve

Comment: ¿Modal? ¿Javascript en una página web? Si lo que se ejecuta en la página web pudiera controlar el equipo donde se ve, sería un riesgo de seguridad (de hecho muchas vulnerabilidades vienen de fallos del navegador para evitar eso). Necesitas algo que tenga permisos para acceder al sistema cliente; p.ej. un plugin del navegador, un applet firmado o una aplicación de escritorio.

Comment: @SJuan76 Si es una página web. Estaba investigando como usar applet, lo que pasa es que hay muchas restricciones con respecto a los navegadores y necesito usar java pues es lo que se me pide. Un plugin? Hay plugin para acceso al sistema? .. Investigaré